# Unable to detect faces from video and save it as image

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, face

The following is the code used to detect face from video(.mp4).
I need to detect the face and save it as image.

```
import cv2
import sys

cascPath = 'haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml'
faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascPath)

video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture('sample.mp4')

while(video_capture.isOpened()):

# Capture frame-by-frame
ret, frame = video_capture.read()

gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(
    gray,
    scaleFactor=1.1,
    minNeighbors=5,
    minSize=(30, 30),
    flags=cv2.cv.CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE
)

# Draw a rectangle around the faces
for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
    cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)

cv2.imshow('Video', frame)

if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
    break

video_capture.release()
```

It is failing at the statement `video_capture.isOpened()`

I tried by giving relative path still it is failing ?

Comment: There is usually indentation after a `:` in Python. Is that needed here?

Answer (score 0):

after i copied **opencv_ffmpeg300.dll** into c://python2.7 folder the issue is resolved

FYI:

The following the the code snippet to save detected face as seperate image

```
crop_img = frame[y:y+h,x:x+w]
cv2.imwrite('E://vijay//frames//frame%d.jpg' %count, crop_img)
count += 1
```